# Modulo operation for max operation in matrix multiplication

Tags: c++, math

I have a function that find maximum value for a range :

A,B,C are 2 d matrices

```
void solve()
{
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                C[i][j] = max(C[i][j],A[i][k]*B[k][j]);
                //C[i][j] can become very large if solve() is called multiple times
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            A[i][j] = C[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

solve() method can be called for large number of times (10^7)

A[i][j] , B[i][j], C[i][j] can be 10^9.

n will be small (about 20).

I need to print final matrix C with modulo m (i.e. C[i][j]%m)

Since we cannot apply mod for intermediate results (it can produce wrong results).

The problem is integer overflow since it can cross max of int and long.

Any suggestions to solve this problem (Any solution other than big int) ?

Comment: What keeps you from doing the modulo only while printing?

Comment: It may be possible C[i][j] > A[i][k]*B[k][j] but C[i][j]%m < A[i][k]*B[k][j]%m

Comment: That is the reason for not doing the modulo during processing, isn't it? I was asking for the reason why you do not do the modulo **after** processing (to keep the results correct), i.e. **only** while printing.

Comment: Integer overflow error will occur.

Comment: So your datatypes are too narrow. If it really is not possible to do while processing (i.e. if no answer is found here) then you need to use wider types, i.e. change `int`to `long long int`. If that does not help you have to change to big-int implementations. There are some libs available for that. However, you will probably not like the performance.

Comment: Editing the info on the integer overflow being the problem would improve the question.

Comment: A[i][j], B[i][j], C[i][j] can be 10^9. so max value can be multiply 10^9 to 10^7 times. With cannot fit in any type

Comment: Do you know the big-int concept? My understanding of it conflicts with your statement "cannot fit in any type".

Comment: Big int can exceed memory limit . looking for simpler solutions

Comment: What is your memory limit? Editing that information into the question would improve it.

Comment: 10^9 * 10^7 = 10^16. Range of `int64_t` ([–9,223,372,036,854,775,808; 9,223,372,036,854,775,807]) should be grant that values can be hold lossless. (9,223,372,036,854,775,807 ~ **9E18**) IMHO, bigint is not necessary.

Comment: The problem is (10^9)*(10^9)*....till 10^7 times.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/gs-codesprint/challenges/currencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is competitive programming you should think out of the box. Since you need to calculate the actual maximum and not the maximum of modulus, you can't use modulo while processing. However:

You are only doing multiplications and you are not worried about the actual value but rather the comparison between different results (to know which is bigger). You can use isomorphism. That is, calculate the log() of the numbers and intermediate results and keep the modulus as auxiliar information. You can do this because a*b < c*d <=> log(a*b) < log(c*d) <=> log(a) + log(b) < log(c) + log(d). So now you only have to do additions between numbers and the value will remain quite small. You will lose some precision but that should be fine considering the context. The problem is that you won't be able to reconstruct the modulus from the log, so you should keep the mod value in a struct or something.